# How to create a replayable events bus on rxjs

Tags: events, rxjs

I need to create an event stream with all the events of my application in it, I need that stream to be replayable and to be able (if needed) to broadcast the old events to later initialized services.

So I've tried using the `ReplaySubject`, but then don't know the operator to avoid replaying if necessary:

```
import {ReplaySubject, of} from 'rxjs'
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/operators'

const bus$ = new ReplaySubject
const one$ = of(1)

// later
bus$.next('foo')
bus$.next('bar')
bus$.next('baz')

// Then I want to subscribe and know about the older events also
bus$.subscribe(doSomething)

// Or I just want the latest values from the subject
bus$
  .pipe(
    combineLatest(one$), 
    // take only the real value from the bus
    map(x => x[0]),
  )
  .subscribe(doSomething)
```

I've found only this contrived solution... I guess there is an operator for that, or I'm simply wrong with my solution and there is a complete different approach...

Thanks in advance!

## Update

Playing around with rxjs 6 I've refined my current solution:

```
import {ReplaySubject, EMPTY} from 'rxjs'
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {unary} from 'ramda'

const eventsBus = new ReplaySubject()

export const events$ = eventsBus
export const latestEvents$ = events$.pipe(combineLatest(EMPTY, unary))
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing what you are looking for is the *withLatestFrom* operator.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html

Sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pym83y

Comment: It seems like an hack to make it work to me, like my solution. I'll experiment and report back if possible, thanks for now!

Comment: BTW I've tried it, but withLatestFrom give only the latest values from the given observable, the original one, will still replay the previous ones

Comment: Yes, that exactly what its for. I think i didnt fully understood your question.

Comment: I need the ReplaySubject to behave like its a normal Subject with an operator if possible :)